# Draggable function in datatable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datatable, datatables

i am making a grid using data table plugin. i am trying to edit the feature given in the link below...

http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/ColVis/style.html

when we click on the button given on the right hand side (below search box) to open the add/remove column dialog box, i am not able to make it draggable. i have replaced all the buttons in the js file with div and i have also added the draggable function in the js file but it is not working.

can someone tell me why is it not working or am i doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried? if I open the console on that page, append the jQuery UI script:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js';
script.id = 'jquery-ui';
$('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

Followed By:

```
$('.ui-buttonset').draggable();
```

Then i can drag the element as expected.

Comment: i have customized the js file by replacing all the buttons with the div's i want the whole dialog box to be draggable i.e div component to be draggable not just a single element. i want to give it the look and feel of popup.

Comment: @user1711574 Did you even try what I gave you? Try it on their live site. Paste all that into the console and click run / press enter. The entire popup window will be draggable.